# Gwt for building an Android application

Tags: android, gwt, cordova, mgwt

I am looking into building my first Android application and was wondering what is the best approach to take for an experienced GWT developer.

During my research I found phone gap which helps you develop for multiple platforms using Html CSS and javascript, when I kept searching I found mgwt and gwt-phonegap which I guess will be great for a GWT developer. Before I start really looking into it I wanted to ask the experienced phone developers around here if I am in the right direction. Maybe using the plain SDK will be easier for me, after all I only want it to run on Android based phones. Maybe someone can offer other alternatives ? My application is pretty simple but demands using some of the phone's APIs like location and notifications.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in this video which explains the basic concepts around mgwt and phonegap: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0V0CdhMFiao&feature=plcp

Of course there are many different ways that you can go with developing a mobile app and GWT and Phonegap is one of them.